# I'm Trying to have a bounce animation on every collision. It's only triggering once

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want the cube to play the bounce animation "Blob" on every collision. It works on the first time then doesn't work ever again.

I have it start at a new state where the animation is not playing.Then when there is a collision it plays the animation.

```
void Start()
{
    m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

}


void Update()
{

}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{


    m_Animator.Play("Blob");


}





}
```

It is supposed to trigger every impact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `Animator Controller` and create a trigger(example  name "Collision") in it, and when you have a collision call the `SetTrigger()`

```
public class WhenCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator m_Animator;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        m_Animator.SetTrigger("Collision");
    }
}
```

[image]